# Does CPython3.5 have deterministic GC?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.5, cpython

In CPython2 no standard library seems to introduce cyclic references, and with the fact that CPython's GC uses reference counting one can be sure that the garbage collection is deterministic. Does this still stand true for CPython3.5 in case if only standard features and libraries are used?

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that _In CPython2 no standard library seems to introduce cyclic references_?

Comment: By trying the most of them.